# I need to hack a C++ compiler to issue and interpret a specific class pointer as index inside a global array

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, clang, memory-segmentation

I have a specific class that is allocated only as element of a global array (imagine as an example handles to files).

```
class MyClass;
MyClass A[1000];
```

I would need to hack a C++ compiler (e.g. g++ or clang) in order to oblige for that class to issue and interpret pointers instead as addresses as indexes inside that array.

So that means that I need the methods of the class to accept the index as "this" pointer and constructors to return instead of the pointer the index inside the array.

Because I am working using the x86 architecture, the conversion of such an index to an "effective address" when the class has size of 1 2 4 or 8 bytes is just a matter of addressing mode.

It may be possible that such a possibility already exists in order to manage some kind of "external pointers" or something similar.

What I have found up to know is the capability inside CLANG described as bellow:

> Annotating a pointer with address space #256 causes it to be code generated relative to the X86 GS segment register, and address space #257 causes it to be relative to the X86 FS segment. Note that this is a very very low-level feature that should only be used if you know what you’re doing (for example in an OS kernel).
>
> Here is an example:
>
> ```
> #define GS_RELATIVE __attribute__((address_space(256)))
> int foo(int GS_RELATIVE *P) {
>    return *P; 
> }
> ```
>
> https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#memory-references-to-specified-segments

That could solve relativeness but not multiplication of index to arrive to the address. But any way it isn't clear how to use it in order to get from object constructors relative addresses.

The question has been put on hold as not enough clear, but I have solved it anyway using finally simple methods, here is a draft to the solution (I arrived lastly) in order to help understand the same question as also a possible solution.

It seems strange that a so convoluted question could be solved with "simple" enough methods. That is exactly the solution I needed because I can use the index as an object.

```
// compilation using g++ on x86 with flags -O3 -m32 

// vect is the class we are acting upon
struct vect{
    int dummy_for_clarity_of_offset;
    int x;
// the "mull" method just multiplies member x with i and j
// according to the regparm(3) convention parameters up to 3 are passed in 
// registers, so the pointer to the vect structure is passed in EAX the i parameter 
// is passed in EDX and the j parameter in ECX (So the order is EAX EDX ECX )
    __attribute__ ((noinline)) __attribute__ ((regparm(3))) void mull(int i,int j){
        asm ("leal (%esi,%eax,8),%eax"); // the index in eax is converted to address
        x*=i*j;
    }
};

register vect* A asm ("%esi"); // the vect* A holds the start address of our array and                     
                              // is a register variable as it is the base of our calcs

// the same operations as above but as a function instead of method
__attribute__ ((noinline)) __attribute__ ((regparm(3))) void mull(vect& a,int i,int j)           

{
    asm ("leal (%esi,%eax,8),%eax");  
    a.x*=i*j;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vect* A1=new(vect[0x10]);
    A=A1;
    A[1].x=9;
    vect* p=(vect*)1; // according to "our convention" should point to A[1]
    int i0=11;int i1=21;
    mull(*p,10,20); // multiplies the member x of A[1] with 10 and 20
    p->mull(i0,i1); // multiplies the member x of A[1] with 11 and 21
}
```

Comment: Sooooo what's the question?

Comment: Even if you can do that I believe result would not worse the effort. Unless the process is more important for you than the result.

Comment: I am essentially searching for some "unknown" "undocumented" capability of some compiler in order to minimize effort.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you need to do this, since C++ offers a lot of flexibility without taking such drastic steps:

- Even for classes that are allocated as elements of a global array, I don't understand what's wrong with using plain old class pointers.
- You can (for example) [overload operator new](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_new.html) to ensure that your class is only allocated within this global array, then use standard pointers after that.
- You could also write your own smart pointer class. It could act as a wrapper around an index into the array and would offer pointer-like semantics (by overloading `*` and `->`) for its users.
- If you know that all of your instances of an object exist within a particular array, then pointer arithmetic makes finding the index of the object is easy:

```
MyObject GlobalArray[];
int GetIndex(const MyObject *obj) {
    return obj - GlobalArray;
}
```

But hacking the C++ compiler itself to change *all* pointers (even `this`) seems like a lot of work and a recipe for a lot of confusion.

Comment: There are two sides of the problem: a) the use of a pointer as relative ( addition subtraction of base address) b) the use of a pointer as index ( multiplication by 2 4 8 and division ). What is more important for me is relativeness because that may offer persistency between saved sessions. I am producing an interpreter and it should be possible to save the whole memory and reload later on. That is the reason I need it. Actually I use "Tokens" and a lot of conversion each time, but I loose in that way the possibility to treat those elements as true objects.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis - A smart pointer (like [Hristo Venew's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25432099/25507)) could overload * and /. This may be a case of "explicit is better than implicit," though: although I haven't actually seen your code, I suspect that it would be better long-term to do some explicit conversions instead of trying to hack magic pointer-like objects into the language (either via compiler modifications or heavy operator overloading).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify the compiler. You can probably go away with your own pointer-like type:

```
ArrayElement array[42];
class MyPointer{
    std::size_t index;
public:
    MyPointer(std::size_t i=0):index(i){}
    ArrayElement &operator*() const{
        return array[index];
    }
    ArrayElement *operator->() const{
        return array+index;
    }
    MyPointer &operator++(){index++;return *this}
    MyPointer operator+(std::size_t i) const{return MyPointer(index+i);}
    MyPointer &operator--(){index--;return *this}
    MyPointer operator-(std::size_t i) const{return MyPointer(index-i);}
    std::ptrdiff_t operator-(MyPointer i) const{return index-i.index;}
    // After a few years when they accept defaulted operators into c++:
    default: ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=;
    // Otherwise write your own boilerplate
};

...
MyPointer p{11};
p->asdf(); // array[11].asdf();
p-=5;
p->asdf(); // array[6].asdf();
```

Comment: In the compiler I use (g++) the implementation of calls to objects takes a hidden argument that is the pointer to the object. Besides that, construction of an object of that kind returns essentially the address of the object. A big part of my code deals with "Tokens" that meaning indexes of objects inside the array. On those pointers I cannot use the technique described by you.

Comment: In the mean while I found the above hint for clang: "Annotating a pointer with address space #256 causes it to be code generated relative to the X86 GS segment register, and address space #257 causes it to be relative to the X86 FS segment. Note that this is a very very low-level feature that should only be used if you know what you’re doing (for example in an OS kernel).

Here is an example:

#define GS_RELATIVE __attribute__((address_space(256)))
int foo(int GS_RELATIVE *P) {
  return *P;
}

So it may be that that kind of "relative segment pointer" could help things.

Comment: gcc 6 as clang now has "Support for address spaces __seg_fs, __seg_gs, and __seg_tls. These can be used to access data via the %fs and %gs segments without having to resort to inline assembly. Please refer to the documentation for usage instructions."